# How to use calc for lineheight in firefox? Its not working

Tags: css, firefox, cross-browser

Is there any other way to use calc for lineheight? It is not working in firefox.

```
lineheight: calc(1.8 * (1vw + 1vh - 1vmin));
```

Comment: Did you tried adding the prefix `-moz-calc` ?

Comment: It works for me. @Treeindev You don't need vendor prefixes for calc.

Comment: @Treeindev It didnt work

Comment: @Rob Is it working for you?

Comment: Check this documentation: https://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/06/css3-calc/

Comment: Yes but not using the values you are using. I inserted a value of 3 for scalar.

Comment: @Treeindev You are referencing an out of date, seven year old article that no longer applies.

Comment: @Rob can you show it in fiddle or plunker ? because its not working for me

Comment: Is this you real code? I mean, did you really type a literal `<scalar>` text?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález no no ..I used the number only..I will update my question.

Answer (score 1):

The correct property name is [`line-height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height), not `lineheight`:

```css
p.styled {
    line-height: calc(1.8 * (1vw + 1vh - 1vmin));
}
```

```html
<p class="regular">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec velit elit, interdum eu ullamcorper at, ultrices quis turpis. Ut non vehicula dui. Etiam vel auctor diam, nec pretium enim. Maecenas porttitor posuere arcu et eleifend. Vivamus maximus ultrices facilisis. Praesent pretium ex et erat vehicula lobortis. Phasellus varius nisl quis odio suscipit, et feugiat magna mollis.</p>

<p class="styled">Aenean elementum tincidunt sem, in egestas turpis interdum at. Cras ac lectus vitae velit aliquam condimentum eu ac justo. Phasellus at neque rhoncus, vestibulum dui quis, molestie augue. Sed vitae laoreet turpis. Phasellus et ligula sapien. Nunc fermentum nisi feugiat augue imperdiet, vel malesuada elit dictum. Quisque mi magna, laoreet id porttitor non, rutrum ac sem. Nam fringilla commodo mi in porta. Phasellus vehicula felis at risus tristique ornare. Vivamus elementum, nisi pharetra accumsan ullamcorper, massa odio consequat libero, ut rhoncus odio magna eu odio. Maecenas imperdiet, diam vel venenatis cursus, nisi nisl rhoncus orci, a sagittis nisi mi ac quam. Fusce fermentum lacus quis nibh rutrum, sed tempus elit tempus. Vivamus non magna sem.</p>
```

Comment: That explains why it worked for me since I typed it out.